# Problem placing or dividing frames in the window (Python with Tkinter/TTKbootstrap)

Tags: python, tkinter, label, frame, ttkbootstrap

I'm trying to put two Labels next to each other but I want one to cover half the window and the other the other half but I've tried everything but nothing happens they just stay in that corner

[how I wanted it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwUiI.png)

I wanted them to look the way I draw them in the image but they just stay there in the corner

```
from textwrap import fill
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class APP:

    def __init__(self):
        # Criando a janela principal
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("FMD")
        self.root.geometry("1080x600")  # Define o tamanho da janela
        # Impede o redimensionamento da janela
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

        # Carregando a imagem existente
        background_image = Image.open("background.png")

        # Convertendo a imagem para o formato Tkinter PhotoImage
        self.background_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_image)

        # Criando um rótulo com a imagem como plano de fundo
        self.background_label = tk.Label(
            self.root, image=self.background_photo)
        self.background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        # Criando o frame do Dataset
        self.dataset_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, bootstyle="dark")
        self.dataset_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.dataset_label = ttk.Label(
            self.dataset_frame, text="Dataset:", bootstyle="inverse-dark")
        self.dataset_label.configure(font=("Arial", 16, "bold"))
        self.dataset_label.pack(side=LEFT)

        # Criando o frame do preview
        self.preview_frame = ttk.Frame(self.root, bootstyle="dark")
        self.preview_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.preview_label = ttk.Label(
            self.preview_frame, text="Preview:", bootstyle="sucess")
        self.preview_label.configure(font=("Arial", 16, "bold"))
        self.preview_label.pack(side=LEFT)

        # Inicia o loop principal da aplicação
        self.root.mainloop()


# Inicializa a aplicação
app = APP()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched Grid to pack *( please anyone correct me if I am wrong but I could not find a way to 'easily' configure the grid column )*.
By using `winfo_width()` you can get the width of the window/object.

```
from tkinter import *

#Tendrás que volver a agregar todas las imágenes e 
# importaciones, las eliminé para poder probarlas.

class APP:

    def __init__(self):
        # Criando a janela principal
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("FMD")
        self.root.geometry("1080x600")  # Define o tamanho da janela
        # Impede o redimensionamento da janela
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

        # Criando o frame do Dataset
        
        # Esto actualiza los datos 'raíz' utilizados para obtener el ancho.
        self.root.update()
        
        # A continuación, obtenga el ancho de la aplicación y divídalo por dos.
        self.dataset_frame = Frame(self.root, width=round(self.root.winfo_width()/2), height=30)
        self.dataset_frame.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=NW)
        
        # Esto está aquí para que el marco no colapse (sin esta línea el marco tendrá un tamaño: 0x0)
        self.dataset_frame.pack_propagate(False)

        self.dataset_label = Label(self.dataset_frame, text="Dataset:", font=("Arial", 16, "bold"))
        self.dataset_label.pack()

        # Criando o frame do preview
        self.preview_frame = Frame(self.root, width=round(self.root.winfo_width()/2), height=30)
        self.preview_frame.pack(side=LEFT, anchor=NW)
        self.preview_frame.pack_propagate(False)

        self.preview_label = Label(self.preview_frame, text="Preview:", font=("Arial", 16, "bold"))
        self.preview_label.pack()

        # Inicia o loop principal da aplicação
        self.root.mainloop()


# Inicializa a aplicação
app = APP()
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want one to cover half the window and the other the other half but
> I've tried everything but nothing happens they just stay in that
> corner

The problem can be fixed.

- Add `width` and `anchor` in Label widgets.

Snippet:

```
self.dataset_label = ttk.Label(self.dataset_frame,
                                       width=50, anchor="n", text="Dataset:",
                                       bootstyle="inverse-dark")
```

and:

```
self.preview_label = ttk.Label(self.preview_frame,
                               width=50, anchor="n",
                               text="Preview:",
                               bootstyle="sucess")
```

Screenshot:

[image]